# OptionalInt vs Optional<Integer>

Tags: java, generics, java-8, language-design

When scrolling through the documentation for the [java.util](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) package, I was surpised to find that `Optional<T>` and `OptionalInt` have no relationship to each other. This seems very hard to belive, as it suggests that they are unrelated classes.

1. Why don't they have a common interface, class, are sub-types, or *something* to reveal the relationship they have? (They're *very* similar classes when you look at their uses.)
2. Also, why the need for an additional `OptionalInt` class? Why can't you just use `Optional<Integer>`? I thought it was due to the fact that `int` is primitive, but there is no `OptionalChar` so that would be an inconsistent design choice.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Java 8 introduced a whole lot dedicated to primitives. The reason is most likely that boxing primitives can create a lot of waste "boxes".

For example this

```
OptionalInt optionalFirst = IntStream
    .range(0, 100)
    .filter(i -> i % 23 > 7)
    .findFirst();
```

Here, an `Optional<Integer>` as result would be inconsistent. Also methods like `ifPresent(IntConsumer consumer)` then allow to stay withing the `IntStream` world. `Optional<Integer>` would force you to convert (which you can do easily if you want)

There is no need for special support for `char` or `short` or `byte` because all of them can be represented as `int`. The missing one is `boolean` but there is not much you can do in a stream with them since there are only 2 values.

Answer (score 15):

There needs to be an `OptionalInt` class for Java 8's streams to be consistent. If you take a look at the [`Stream` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), you'll see that [many](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) [of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) [the](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) return `Optional<T>`. However, dealing with a `Stream<Integer>`, `Stream<Long>` or any other streams of primitives is exhausting, so there is an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) class and a [`LongStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html) class which replace the object with its unboxed value. For instance, finding the sum of the elements of a `Stream<Integer>` is not trivial, whereas for an `IntStream`, you just call [`IntStream#sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--)

In these classes, the JDK helpfully replaces `Optional<T>` with `OptionalInt`, `OptionalLong`, and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

`OptionalInt` is a container holding value of primitive type `int`. Primitive types cannot be used as type parameters for generic classes, so there is no way it could be a subclass of `Optional<T>`.

Comment: So then why isn't there `OptionalChar`?

Comment: zapl answered that in the question comment.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why `Optional<Integer>` is insufficient. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Michael because there are times that you don't want to incur the cost from the overhead of autoboxing primitives. Logically, you are right, they are otherwise redundant. They only did this for the most commonly used types since they didn't want to have to add too many classes. Same with `IntConsumer` and `DoubleConsumer` but no `CharConsumer`. Mind you with Java 9 you should be  (plans can change) able to be generic over primitives and this will all be legacy.