# Why optionalLong/Double and orElseThrow?

Tags: java, java-10

With release of `Java-11`, Why do we have `orElseThrow` with `optionalLong` / `OptionalDouble` and other `Optional Types` when we can directly check if a number is not null or not equals to a specific number.

Also, we were doing null checks which were better than throwing an Exception?

May be not able to visualize the real use of `optionalTypes` and `orElseThrow`.

Javadoc for [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalLong.html#orElseThrow()).

Comment: The  whole point of optionals is to avoid null checks (with primitives, you can't even do null checks).

Comment: `OptionalLong` and `OptionalDouble` wrap **primitives**. If we wanted to wrap a boxed value, we could just use `Optional<Long>`. A primitive cannot be null.

Comment: @RealSkeptic But how throwing an exception is better than a null check?

Comment: @Chetnarustagi Throwing an exception is what you do as the result of the null check. `orElseThrow` lets you do the same thing. It is a shorter version of `x.isPresent() ? x.get() : throw SomeException()` (not sure if that even compiles, maybe needs to be even longer). Yes, you could do that directly, but why not have a helper for it.

Comment: Is this question specific to `OptionalLong` or `orElseThrow` in general (all Optional types have that)?

Comment: It's just an improved naming of `getAs..` if I could say so to explicitly say that the API can throw an exception.

Comment: @Chetnarustagi I've updated the question with the Javadoc link. Feel free to revert the edit if it contradicts the API you've mentioned in the question. You can also follow [JDK-8140281](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8140281) which mentions more explicitly the reason for the introduction of the API. It would also make a lot more sense if you can edit the question to quote [tag:java-10] specifically.

Comment: @Thilo Its for all Optional Types.

Answer (score 3):

> Why do we have orElseThrow with optionalLong / OptionalDouble when we
>   can directly check if a number is not null or not equals to a specific
>   number.

Not really, `Optional`s are designed for return types, not for checking input parameters. 
In the later cases, checking not null or range validity (for primitives)  makes more sense.
Besides, these features are not new. Java 8 already introduced these functions.

---

To illustrate the interest of `OptionalLong.orElseThrow()`, suppose a case where you search a `long` id from a method but that id may not be found.
Here is a code that handles the not found value case.

Without `OptionalLong`, you should choose an arbitrary long value to convey the not found result :

```
long id = compute();  // returns -1. By hopping that it not a valid id...
```

Then, from the client side, you have to dig into the implementation of `compute()` to know if the id value can be empty and whether is the case, which value represents the emptiness.
And at last you could write that :

```
if (id == -1){
   throw  new IllegalArgumentException("the id is mandatory");
}
```

Suppose that tomorrow `-1` be a valid id, so you should change both the implementation and the client code to be aware of it : not maintainable at all and very error prone.

With `OptionalLong` the approach is much more robust :

```
OptionalLong optId = compute(); // returns OptionalLong.empty();
```

As a client of `compute()` you know that the id may be empty (`Optional` semantic) and you know also how to handle it in a standard way: the Optional` unwrapping functions.

```
long mandatoryId = optId.orElseThrow( ()-> new IllegalArgumentException("the id is mandatory");
```

---

Here `OptionalLong` or even `Optional<Long>` provides a triple advantage (about the difference between them I advise [the excellent answer of Nishant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57288891/270371)) :

- living documentation of the emptiness case return
- robustness way for clients to convey the emptiness value (versus the `-1` approach).
- standard way to convey and handle the emptiness return (`Optional` and its functions)

But in a general way, `Optional`s with `Object`s contained in provides "only" these two advantages :

- living documentation of the emptiness case return
- standard way to convey and handle the emptiness return (`Optional` and its functions)

Answer (score 3):

I randomly chose a method from `com.google.common.io` API which demonstrates the use of `Optional<Long>`. They use own `Optional` type, but the concept is identical.

```
@Override
public Optional<Long> sizeIfKnown() {
  if (file.isFile()) {
    return Optional.of(file.length());
  } else {
    return Optional.absent();
  }
}
```

Due to the absence of `OptionalLong`, they are auto-wrapping `file.length()`, which returns a `long`, into an `Optional<Long>`. They don't want `sizeIfKnown` to throw an exception. They don't want `sizeIfKnown` to introduce a magical return value which would indicate the absence of a value.

Instead, they want to say "we return a `long`, or nothing".

With Java 11, it would look a bit cleaner, and a bit simpler

```
@Override
public OptionalLong sizeIfKnown() {
  if (file.isFile()) {
    return OptionalLong.of(file.length());
  } else {
    return OptionalLong.empty();
  }
}
```

Regarding `orElseThrow`, it's relatively old feature introduced in Java 8 to control execution flow in a functional manner. It does exactly what you described: a `null` check and a `throw` statement.

```
if (value != null) {
    return value;
} else {
    throw exceptionSupplier.get();
}
```

Comment: Contrast this to `String#indexOf` which returns a magical `-1` for missing values. People have to read the documentation to understand that. With OptionalInt, it is expressed in the type.

Comment: Better yet, `return Optional.of(file).filter(File::isFile).mapToLong(File::length)`. edit: oh wait, `Optional` doesn't have `mapToLong`... Shame. Would need to be `Optional<Long>`.

Comment: Might have misunderstood, but how does this relate to `orElseThrow` introduced in the JDK?

Comment: @Naman it doesn't. I answered the part about java 11 new `Optional`s. `orElseThrow` is a different story, I remember there was a discussion about it, I will add a link to it

Comment: *java 11 new Optionals* .. what does that mean? The question was always about `orElseThrow` in first place. :)

Comment: @Naman `OptionalLong`, and `OptionalDouble` which were mentioned before `orElseThrow`

Comment: From the question (emphasis mine) *Why do we have `orElseThrow` **with** `OptionalLong` / `OptionalDouble`*. Anyway, the example shared is helpful to understand the concepts, just unrelated to the question in my opinion.

Comment: @Naman I have no idea how to answer this question :) The same reason why we have `orElseThrow` with other `Optional` types? (which is a short, handy, functional-like way to express non-functional statements and to handle the value received from `Optional`)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add the following to davidxxx's answer

To maintain consistency with primitive streams, primitive optionals are included in the API. Refer this answer - [OptionalInt vs Optional<Integer>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190768/optionalint-vs-optionalinteger).

However, their usage is discouraged because they lack the `map`, `flatMap`, and `filter` methods, which are the most useful methods of the `Optional` class.

Also, just like streams, an optional can’t be composed with its primitive counterpart, so if a method returned an `OptionalDouble`, you couldn’t pass it as a method reference to the `flatMap` method of another optional.

Comment: Very good point. I agreed completely about the limitation of `OptionalInt/Long/Double` for such a low gain : a single primitive instead of a wrapper object.

Answer (score 0):

`Optional`s (like most new Java language features) do not allow you to do anything you couldn't do before. They simply make it easier to read/write code.

Consider the following code, which does a complicated calculation to work out a person's probability of having a certain disease:

```
private static final int PROBABILITY_UNKNOWN = -1;
// in the class definition

double probability = doCalculation();
if (probability == PROBABILITY_UNKNOWN) {
    throw new ProbabilityUnknownException();
} else {
    process(probability);  // or whatever
}
```

This code works. Note that `probability` cannot be `null`, since it is a primitive. Compare this, however, to the same code written with `Optional`. In this code, instead of `doCalculation()` returning `-1` when unable to calculate, it returns an empty optional (`OptionalDouble.empty()`):

```
OptionalDouble opt = doCalculation();
opt.ifPresent(this::process);
opt.orElseThrow(() -> new ProbabilityUnknownException());
```

There are a few advantages to this, mainly readability, but also the fact that you no longer need to define a `null value`. In this case, it is easy to choose a `double` value that represents the absence of a value, since a probability can never be -1. However, for values which have no such obvious value, `Optional` provides useful functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`OptionalLong` and `OptionalDouble` provide both methods `orElse(long)` to return a default value, if the optional value is not present and `orElseThrow` which throws an exception instead.

In general you are right that you should avoid throwing Exceptions. In this case you could just do nothing in the case the optional value is not present of proceed with a default value using `orElse()`.

But sometimes it is required to have a loaded value to proceed a computation but your source e.g. a database just cannot provide it. In this case it would be wrong to proceed without a value or a default value and you should use `orElseThrow` to throw an Exception and handle how to react on that on a different level. It's the same behavior `Optional<Long>` provides.

The difference between `Optional<Long>` and `OptionalLong` is that `OptionalLong` directly holds the value in a primitive `long` which consumes less memory. `Optional<Long>` is an Object holding a `Long` object which wraps the primitive `long` value. This is one object more to manage. So `OptionalLong` will give you a slightly better performance compared to `Optional<Long>`.